# ASP.NET Reader failure to retrieve values

Tags: asp.net, forms

I am trying to read values to a text box after searching from the database using a store procedure. See sample code below:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string firstname = reader["FirstName"].ToString().Trim();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
    {
        string fullName = reader["FirstName"].ToString().Trim() + 
        reader["LastName"].ToString().Trim();

        labelFname = reader["FirstName"].ToString().Trim();
        labelSname = reader["LastName"].ToString().Trim();
        msg = "Retrieval Successful";
    }
}
```

I am able to get the value in `fullname` and `labelFname` but I am not able to proceed to `labelSname`. This is a method and am passing the values as below:

Comment: Are you sure, you have value against LastName?

Comment: Secondly, you are getting last name in FullName string ?

Comment: what error message are you receiving, i.e. why can't you proceed to labelSname?

Comment: Yes, I have value in all FullName and Lastname:

Comment: I have values on all the fields. And I am calling this method like this:
saveToDb.SeachCHIs(resul, this.txtName.Text, this.txtSname.Text);
If I dont use it as a method , it returns all values BUT if I try to call it as a method, it fails.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar /@ Barry
If I call this as a method it fails, but if I just add it as event behind a button it works

Comment: Can you take some time to how to format your code snippets properly. Also you appear to be missing something from the end after this sentence? **This is a method and am passing the values as below:**

Comment: You could also do with simplifying your code... why do you repeatedly call `reader["FirstName"].ToString().Trim()` when you have already set the value into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the field value is `null` and you are calling a `Trim` method on that `null` object and it is throwing an error. Do proper null check before accessing the values.

```
string msg =string.empty;
while (reader.Read())
{
    string fName=string.empty;
    string lName=string.empty;
    string fullName=string.empty;

    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName")))
         fName = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName"));

    if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName")))
         lName= reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("LastName"));

    fullName=fName.Trim()+ " "+lName.Trim();
    msg = "Retrieval Successful";

}
```

**EDIT :** It is always a good practice to store the Ordinal Indexes to a variable and use that instead of calling `GetOrdinal` everytime inside a loop, especially dealing with so many records. It will bring up some speed to your code execution.

```
int fNameLocation = reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName");
while (reader.Read())
{
    string fName=string.empty;
    string lName=string.empty;
    string fullName=string.empty;

    if (!reader.IsDBNull(fNameLocation))
         fName = reader.GetString(fNameLocation );

    //process Other fields
}
```